# Errors with xutility (<chrono> <random> C++ standard libraries)

Tags: c++, random, visual-studio-2013, c++-chrono

I am having an issue writing a simple random number generator using the standard  and  in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. When I attempt to compile, it throws a bunch of errors related to the xutility file. I had a bunch of similar errors thrown when I attempted to use the BOOST libraries to accomplish the same thing, so it MAY be an issue with MSVC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

auto seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

int main()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> randNum(1, 6);

    cout << randNum(seed) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors it is throwing:

Error   1   error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of 'std::chrono::time_point'    e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3256

Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_Ty1'    e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3256

Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3256

Error   4   error C2065: '_Ty1' : undeclared identifier e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3258

Error   5   error C2070: 'unknown-type': illegal sizeof operand e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3258

Error   6   error C2065: '_Ty1' : undeclared identifier e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3259

Error   7   error C2923: 'std::_If' : '_Ty1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty2' e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3259

Error   8   error C2955: 'std::_If' : use of class template requires template argument list e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 3259

Here is the section of code from xutility that seems to be causing trouble:

```
    // TEMPLATE CLASS _Rng_from_urng
template<class _Diff, class _Urng>
    class _Rng_from_urng
    {   // wrap a URNG as an RNG
public:
    typedef typename make_unsigned<_Diff>::type _Ty0;
    typedef typename _Urng::result_type _Ty1;

    typedef typename _If<sizeof (_Ty1) < sizeof (_Ty0),
        _Ty0, _Ty1>::type _Udiff;
```

The class has a LOT more code after this point, but the errors are happening in these last two lines.

By the way, I spent several hours querying different searches to try and find an answer before posting here with no usable results, though that could easily be a deficiency on my part.

Thanks!

With Sebastion's help, all previous errors were resolved, however a new error has been generated:

Modified code:

```
    std::default_random_engine engine(seed);

    cout << randNum(engine) << endl;
```

Error:

Error   1   error C2039: 'generate' : is not a member of 'std::chrono::time_point'   e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\random   1618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `cout << randNum(seed) << endl;`

That's now how you use a distribution. You need to create a local engine that you initialize with the seed, and then pass the *engine* to the distribution's call operator.

```
std::default_random_engine engine(seed);
cout << randNum(engine) << endl;
```

See the example at cppreference for a more elaborate example:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Thank you! That resolved those errors and created a new one:


Error 1 error C2039: 'generate' : is not a member of 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::system_clock::duration>' e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\random 1618

Comment: I find it interesting that the errors all seemed to give zero help with the actual issue. :/

Comment: That's why concepts are planned for C++: so that errors like this can be diagnosed at the call site.